# how to remove digits of number in java?

Tags: java

In the java, how to remove digits of number in an efficient way ? for example, I have 13 digits number, I want to remove the first 3 digits:

Some code:

```
long largeNumber = 1234567890123L;
long finalNumber = removeFirstDigits(largeNumber, 3); // finalNumber == 4567890123L
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and a specific problem on it.

Comment: or you can put it into string and manipulate any way you want.And then change back to datatype you want to use

Comment: Dividing by 10 would remove the LAST digit, not the FIRST THREE digits.

Comment: first 3 digits would be division by 1000.

Comment: long number = 1234567890123L; long newNumber = number%10000000000L;

Comment: Best practice is to start coding

Comment: @RobinGreen i never understood what are the firsts and the lasts xD, i prefer right and left

Comment: Can you add examples of input and expected output? Can numbers be placed inside long text which you want to change? Can they be surrounded with other characters like `-123` `ab314`? Also how are you trying to solve it now?

Comment: I would prefer @Pshemo's solution. If they can be sorrouned by any special character, use StringTokenizer to seperate the digits

Comment: I think this question is interesting, we have two implementations, string and math based. We still dont know which one is more efficient :)

Answer (score 12):

When you deal with representations of numbers in base `B`, the trick to removing leading digits is using remainders of division by powers of the base `B`; to remove trailing digits, use integer division by powers of the base.

Specifically, to remove `k` leading decimal digits of an `n`-digit decimal number `X`, obtain the remainder of the division of `X` by ten to the power of `n-k`:

```
int X = 12345678; // n = 8
// Remove 3 leading digits (k=3)
// 10 ^ (n-k) = 10 ^ 5 = 100000
int res = X % 100000; // res = 45678
```

To remove the trailing `k` decimal digits, use integer division by 10 ^ 3:

```
int X = 12345678;
int res = X / 1000; // res = 12345
```

Comment: +1 For mathematical approach

Comment: this assumes though, that you always know how many digits your nr. has

Comment: @cytofu and others who have the same question, check this answer to get the number of digits from a number: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/438781

Comment: or simply do: `String.valueOf(12345678).length()`

Comment: @MariuszS If you do `String.valueOf(12345678)`, you might as well use `substr`.

Comment: Then we can do that: `(int) (Math.log10(number) + 1;` like Alex said.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical version

```
private long removeFirstDigits(long number, int left) {
    return number % (long) Math.pow(10, (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1) - left);
}
```

String version

```
private long removeFirstDigits(long number, int left) {
    String string = String.valueOf(number);
    return Long.parseLong(string.substring(left, string.length()));
}
```

I dont know which version is much efficient and faster. Microbanchmark can help determining this.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the cleanest, but you can always use String:

```
long largeNumber = 123456789101l;
String largeNumberInString = String.valueOf(largeNumber);
long resultingNumber = Long.parseLong(largeNumberInString.substring(3, largeNumberInString.length()));
```